# Javascript logo moving mouseover functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually I am beginner in JavaScript, I need one requirement for JavaScript Functionality.
Whenever I mouse over my logo that logo should be moved over the body. This means when I place my mouse cursor over the logo, it should leave that place and move to some other place.

I am trying but the code is not working for me. Can any one suggest me in this regard. For reference I am pasting the link below for gif image.

```
<script type="javascript">
    $("#logo").mouseover(function(){
        if(!logoMove){return;}
        var tmp=new Array(
            {left:10,                               top:10},
            {left:10,                               top:$("#bodycontainer").height()-220},
            {left:$("#bodycontainer").width()-220,  top:$("#bodycontainer").height()-220},
            {left:$("#bodycontainer").width()/2,    top:$("#bodycontainer").height()/2},
            {left:$("#bodycontainer").width()-220,  top:20}
        );
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * tmp.length);
        while(tmp[rand].left == $(this).css("left") &&
            tmp[rand].top == $(this).css("top")){
            rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * tmp.length);
        }
        $(this).stop().animate({
                left:tmp[rand].left,
                top:tmp[rand].top
            },
            400
        );
    });
}
<script>

<div id="logo">
    <img width="500" height="462" src="http://www.gameark.com/templates/onarcade/images/logo.png" >
</div>
```

For reference click [link.](http://www.gameark.com/)

Comment: Take a look on this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031701/moving-an-image-10px-on-hover-and-changing-opacity

Comment: Here's a post i found. Try this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929687/tricky-button-moving-away-when-mouseover-in-javascriptl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var logoMoved = false;
var _k = 0;
$("#logo").on("mouseenter",function(){
    if(logoMoved) return;
    var tmp = [
        {
            left:10, 
            top:10
        },
        {
            left:10,
            top:$("#bodycontainer").height()-220
        },
        {
            left:$("#bodycontainer").width()-220,
            top:$("#bodycontainer").height()-220
        },
        {
            left:$("#bodycontainer").width()/2,
            top:$("#bodycontainer").height()/2
        },
        {
            left:$("#bodycontainer").width()-220,
            top:20
        }
    ];
    logoMoved = true;
    var _n = Math.floor(Math.random() * tmp.length);;
    while(_k == _n){
         _n = Math.floor(Math.random() * tmp.length);
    }
    _k = _n;
    $(this).animate({
        left:tmp[_k].left,
        top:tmp[_k].top
    },400,function(){
        logoMoved = false;
    });
});
```

you can use one of two ways:

1. stop() on $(this).animate to stop the current animation and do an other (i don't like this way)
2. logoMoved variables to prevent mouseover before anuimation ended.

in your example you use both... it's seems useless.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/8g3wy/1/ 
I hope it can help.

Comment: Thank You Frogmouth. This is what i have expected.

Comment: yeee... I'm glad to have help.